# Apache XML RPC Client Library equivalent call using OkHttp3 for Odoo v9 Web Service API

Tags: android, xml, web-services, odoo-9, okhttp

I want to use `OkHttp3` library to connect with `Odoo v9 server` for my `Android` application. There's [odoo-rpc-v3](https://github.com/Odoo-mobile/framework/tree/master/odoo-rpc-v3) already available which internally uses `android Volly library` and sometimes `throws NullPointerException` with no `error messages` which is out of my control & crashes the application. [Here's](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/api_integration.html) the **Odoo v9 Web Services API Docs** which is wriiten using **Apache XML-RPC library** in **Java**. I want execute same call using of **OkHttp3** library.

The Calls are:
1. Logging in

```
final XmlRpcClient client = new XmlRpcClient();
final XmlRpcClientConfigImpl common_config = new XmlRpcClientConfigImpl();
common_config.setServerURL(
    new URL(String.format("%s/xmlrpc/2/common", url)));
client.execute(common_config, "version", emptyList());
int uid = (int)client.execute(
    common_config, "authenticate", asList(
        db, username, password, emptyMap()
    )
);
```

2. Calling methods

```
final XmlRpcClient models = new XmlRpcClient() {{
    setConfig(new XmlRpcClientConfigImpl() {{
        setServerURL(new URL(String.format("%s/xmlrpc/2/object", url)));
    }});
}};
models.execute("execute_kw", asList(
    db, uid, password,
    "res.partner", "check_access_rights",
    asList("read"),
    new HashMap() {{ put("raise_exception", false); }}
));
```

Ultimately I want to use **XML-RPC** using **OkHttp3**.
Any suggestions, guidelines or help are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey Can you help me in this?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46067346/is-there-anyone-integratted-odoo-with-android

Comment: Yes, use jsonRPC, there're lot of jsonRPC library already written in JS. Write down same in Java.
Look at this https://github.com/akretion/odoo-json-rpc

Comment: Also look at https://github.com/Odoo-mobile/framework

Comment: Which xml-rpc jar file is you used??

Comment: for offline capability I use https://github.com/Odoo-mobile/framework
for normal app I write own my HTTP request by getting help from OdooWrapper.java at https://github.com/Odoo-mobile/framework/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/odoo/core/rpc/wrapper/OdooWrapper.java

Comment: this frame work is for creating apps right??

Comment: yes, https://github.com/Odoo-mobile/framework is use for creating apps

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153922/discussion-between-noufal-and-ka7im1011).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fianlly I've done this using `Odoo json-rpc`. here's the [demo](https://github.com/kasim1011/OdooJsonRpcClient). If you like it, give me a star :).

Comment: share me source code please, the demo link not found